# How to expose application in a custom class file in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my project's app.xaml.cs I added two member variables of type UserProfile, and ExercisePlan. I added these so that I could access them project wide. In my custom class ExercisePlan I am creating another member variable of type UserProfile. I want to set this UserProfile variable equal to Application.Current.UserProfile.

In theory I want to set the variable in my class equal to the current user of the application. when I try this VS tells me Application.Current does not exist.

I did something similar like this already but it was in a .xaml.cs file not a custom class file.

New WPF so if theres a better way to do all of these please teach me

```
namespace TrackFit_Project
{
  public partial class App : Application
  {
    #region Member Variables

    private UserProfile user;
    private ExercisePlan exercisePlan;

    #endregion
  }
}

namespace TrackFit_Project
{
  public class ExercisePlan
  {

    #region Member Variables

    // This is where my issue is
    // public UserProfile _user = Application.Current.UserProfile();

    #endregion
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use the application settings maybe? I'm not not sure what's the problem you're facing though ...

Comment: _"I want to set this UserProfile variable equal to Application.Current.UserProfile"_ -- then you should set it from the application code, not the custom class. Frankly, it's probably not a great idea to have this design anyway. And probably you could get access to `Application.Current` by adding the necessary `using` directive (you'd still need to cast to your own `App` type), assuming this "custom class file" is part of the same project (e.g. `using System.Windows;`).

Comment: But if you must have these two variables/properties and you want to copy from one place to the other, you should at least minimize the coupling between your classes by having the dependent code (the application) refer to the supporting code, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Thank you responding! let me try to explain more clearly. So in my App.xaml.cs I added a variable (private UserProfile _user;). I placed this in App because it seemed like a good place to put it if i want to easily access this variable through-out the code. i am able to use Application.current in any .xaml.cs files but not in regular .cs class file that im making. and thats my issue

Answer (score 0):

TBH, it sounds like a bit of dependency injection will go a great distance for you here...
Example:

```
class foo { 
   private string my_foo;
   public void foo(string injected){ my_foo = injected; } // dependency was injected
   // more stuff
}
```

You can use something like `Autofac` to do this for you, or just do it manually by passing the variables to your classes.
Bottom line is the same, you get the variables you need, without dependency on other modules, and you can easily mock them out when unit testing your application (because, you do unit test your application, right? )

Comment: I dont understand this solution :(. is class foo my custom class or App.xaml.cs

Comment: class foo is your custom class, and it gets injected whatever dependencies it needs. Google it up, do some reading, there's even a [video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKD2-MAkXyQ) (i didn't watch it, but i guess it'll give you an idea)