# WPF where should i be putting object that I need project wide

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm new to WPF and .NET. I'm making a fitness application where the user makes an account. Naturally I need to access my `UserProfile` class object in multiple places in my code. Where should I define and assign the instance of the current `UserProfile` in my solution? My first instinct is `App.xaml` but there is probably a better way.

Comment: why do you repeat the same question again and again:(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119679/wpf-how-to-get-app-obj-in-a-custom-class, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080721/how-to-expose-application-in-a-custom-class-file-in-wpf) ? Edit existing one. This post is awfully worded

Comment: Im sorry, new to posting on stackoverflow. My original question didnt produce any answers that worked out for me and people stopped answering so i figured the post died.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF how to get App obj in a custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119679/wpf-how-to-get-app-obj-in-a-custom-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for example create a static class:

```
public static class ApplicationService
{
    public static UserProfile User { get; set; }
}
```

You can then access it from any other class in your application like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //set:
    ApplicationService.User = ...;
    //get:
    var user = ApplicationService.User;
}
```